# Filemaker plugin development in c# IDE for window

Tags: filemaker

Is there any IDE  which allow to produce .fmx file  extension, Actually i am developing filemaker plugin with  .fmx extension so that i can simply put it in "Extension" folder in where tha all plugin is resided used by filemaker pro application software and start using, when i tried to search extension .fmx in visual basic 2008 then it didn't show any result , still i am searching over internet, but i am not able to find. please sugest me some alternative, or some thing related

Thanks,
Nishant

Answer (score 0):

FileMaker plug-ins are regular Win32 DLLs. The `.fmx` extension is just a custom extension. I'm not sure you can produce such a DLL with Visual Basic or C# (but I'm not an expert in these); you might have to use Visual C++.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://www.dotnet2fm.com/ They provide a tool to write filemaker plugin in c#